# why spring boot test cannot recognise property value?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

spring boot + jdbctemplate

```
@Configuration
public class MultiDBConfig implements BeanPostProcessor{

    @Value("${spring.datasource.test-while-idle}")
    private boolean  testWhileIdle;
    //...
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if(bean instanceof org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource){
            org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) bean;
            ds.setTestWhileIdle(testWhileIdle);

        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

and I have a `UserDaoTest` and at first I only want just to test it without load other components

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@JdbcTest(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,value=UserDao.class))
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Import(MultiDBConfig.class)
public class UserDaoTest {}
```

When execute test I got below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${spring.datasource.test-while-idle}]
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor.setAsText(CustomBooleanEditor.java:123)
```

but if changes `UserDaoTest` to

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserDaoTest {...}
```

it's ok.

So why in case one it does not resolve `spring.datasource.test-while-idle` properly and how could solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to import the `applicaton.properties` or `application.yml` file that holds that property.

Comment: but how? I tried `@TestPropertySource` and `@PropertySource` but they both not work

Comment: Try this http://www.javarticles.com/2016/02/spring-testpropertysource-annotation-example.html